# Cannot setup Magento 2.3 in local due to autoload error?

Tags: magento2.3, localhost, ubuntu, autoloader

I have done manual backup of my site and setup it on local bit getting the below error:

```
Autoload error:

Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.
```

Can anyone please help me to rectify this error?

Comment: try to run composer update and deployment commands.

Comment: Have you run `composer install` and `composer update` using cli?

Comment: Please check your vendor directory if that is empty then run `composer install` once and then run deployment commands.

Comment: I'm getting the below error when I run composer update: [ErrorException]                                                             
  copy(/home/monika/.composer/cache/files/zendframework/zend-session/8445ecbb  
  8ab9213c5b500536ff7d96ee51387b0c.zip): failed to open stream: Permission de  
  nied

Comment: Have you tried to give permission to var, pub and generated folder.
Also, remove the data from the var/cache and generated.

Comment: Yes, I have given permission to those folders but still getting the same error

Comment: Try to run sudo composer install

Comment: @KamleshSolanki, Thanks, I have tried to run sudo composer install. Now, most of the modules have installed but getting the below error [UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  The checksum verification of the file failed (downloaded from https://api.g  
  ithub.com/repos/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-enterprise/zipball/9  
  16c6968554cefcac28922a9d261d851f0b0f111)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have solved this issue by running the following commands:

```
sudo composer install
sudo composer update
```

After that the deployment commands. So, here I have added sudo with composer install and update. Thanks for all your suggestions that make me resolve this issue.